# Differences in Promises in jQuery

Tags: jquery, promise

What are the differences between:

```
$.when(myFunction1()).then(myFunction2)
$.when(myFunction1()).then(myFunction2())
myFunction1().then(myFunction2)
myFunction1().then(myFunction2())
```

where the functions inside return some ajax promise

```
return $.ajax( ... );
```

Comment: There is no real difference as long as the function return a deferred promise

Comment: @adeneo - it does affect the timing of when `myFunction2` is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in result between the 1st and 3rd options.  There is no difference in result between the 2nd and 4th options.  The added `$.when()` is not needed, but does not change the result.

The difference between the 1st/3rd and 2nd/4th are in the timing of when `myFunction2` is run.

The 2nd and 4th options call `myFunction2` immediately.  The 1st and 3rd options don't call `myFunction2` until the first promise is resolved.

---

If `myFunction2` is just a normal function that you want executed only after the `myFunction1` promise is resolved, then the fact that the 1st and 3rd options will wait to execute `myFunction2` until the `myFunction1` promise is resolved can make a material difference.

So, if all functions return a promise that's returned from `$.ajax(...)`, then the difference between the 1st/3rd and 2nd/4th will be in the timing of when the `myFunction2` ajax calls are run.  The 2nd and 4th will run the `myFunction2` ajax call in parallel with the `myFunction1` ajax call (e.g. at the same time).  The 1st and 3rd will wait for the `myFunction1` ajax call to be done before executing the `myFunction2` ajax calls.

---

As long as `myFunction1` returns a promise, there is no difference in the result between these two:

```
$.when(myFunction1()).then(myFunction2)
myFunction1().then(myFunction2)
```

`$.when()` is not needed at all when only passing it a single promise.  Its purpose in life is to wait for multiple promises.  So, if you only have a single promise, then the second option above is simply more efficient - just use `.then()` on the promise you already have.

Comment: very nice, explained a lot